# A* Pathfinding - how to modify G and H to include rough terrain movement cost?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, path-finding, shortest-path, a-star

I have A* pathfinding implemented in my 2D game and it works well on a plain map with obstacles. Now I'm trying to understand how to modify the algorithm, so it counts rough terrain (hills, forest, etc) as 2 moves instead of 1.

With the 1 movement cost, the algorithm uses integers 10 and 14 in the move cost function. **Im interested in how to modify these values if one cell actually has a movement cost of 2?**  will it be 20:17?

Here's how my current algorithm currently computes G and H ([adopted from Ray Wenderleich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding)):

```
    // Compute the H score from a position to another (from the current position to the final desired position
    - (int)computeHScoreFromCoord:(CGPoint)fromCoord toCoord:(CGPoint)toCoord
    {
        // Here we use the Manhattan method, which calculates the total number of step moved horizontally and vertically to reach the
        // final desired step from the current step, ignoring any obstacles that may be in the way
        return abs(toCoord.x - fromCoord.x) + abs(toCoord.y - fromCoord.y);
    }

    // Compute the cost of moving from a step to an adjecent one
    - (int)costToMoveFromStep:(ShortestPathStep *)fromStep toAdjacentStep:(ShortestPathStep *)toStep
    {
        return ((fromStep.position.x != toStep.position.x)
 && (fromStep.position.y != toStep.position.y))
 ? 14 : 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If some of the edges have movement cost 2, you will simply add 2 to the G of the parent node, rather than 1.

As for H:  it doesn't need to change.  The resulting heuristic will still be admissible/consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, with this line the tutorial author checks if the move is 1 square or 2 squares(diagonal) from the move that is currently being considered.

```
return ((fromStep.position.x != toStep.position.x)
 && (fromStep.position.y != toStep.position.y))
 ? 14 : 10;
```

Unfortunately, this is a really simple case and does not really explain what has to be done. Number 10 is used to make calculations easier (10 = 1 move cost), and (14 = 1 diagonal move) is an approximation of sqrt(10*10).

I attempted to introduce terrain cost below, and this requires extra information - I need to know which cell I'm going through to reach the destination. This turned out to be really annoying, and the code below is clearly not my best, but I attempted to spell out what's going on at each step.

If I'm making a diagonal move, I need to know it's move cost AND the move cost of 2 squares that can be used to get there. I can then pick the lowest movement cost among two squares and plug it into the equation of the form:

```
moveCost =  (int)sqrt(lowestMoveCost*lowestMoveCost + (stepNode.moveCost*10) * (stepNode.moveCost*10));
```

Here's the entire loop that checks adjacent steps and creates new steps out of them with the move cost. It finds tile in my map array and returns it's terrain cost.

```
    NSArray *adjSteps = [self walkableAdjacentTilesCoordForTileCoord:currentStep.position];
        for (NSValue *v in adjSteps) {

            ShortestPathStep *step = [[ShortestPathStep alloc] initWithPosition:[v CGPointValue]];


            // Check if the step isn't already in the closed set
            if ([self.spClosedSteps containsObject:step]) {

                continue; // Ignore it
            }


            tileIndex = [MapOfTiles tileIndexForCoordinate:step.position];
            DLog(@"point (x%.0f y%.0f):%i",step.position.x,step.position.y,tileIndex);

            stepNode = [[MapOfTiles sharedInstance] mapTiles] [tileIndex];



//            int moveCost = [self costToMoveFromStep:currentStep toAdjacentStep:step];

            //in my case 0,0 is bottom left, y points up x points right
            if((currentStep.position.x != step.position.x) && (currentStep.position.y != step.position.y))
            {
                //move one step away - easy, multiply move cost by 10
                moveCost = stepNode.moveCost*10;
            }else
            {
                possibleMove1 = 0;
                possibleMove2 = 0;

                //we are moving diagonally, figure out in which direction
                if(step.position.y > currentStep.position.y)
                {
                    //moving up
                    possibleMove1 = tileIndex + 1;

                    if(step.position.x > currentStep.position.x)
                    {
                        //moving right and up
                         possibleMove2 = tileIndex + tileCountTall;

                    }else
                    {
                        //moving left and up
                        possibleMove2 = tileIndex - tileCountTall;
                    }


                }else
                {
                    //moving down
                    possibleMove1 = tileIndex - 1;

                    if(step.position.x > currentStep.position.x)
                    {
                        //moving right and down
                        possibleMove2 = tileIndex + tileCountTall;
                    }else
                    {
                        //moving left and down
                        possibleMove2 = tileIndex - tileCountTall;
                    }

                }


                moveNode1 = nil;
                moveNode2 = nil;

                CGPoint coordinate1 = [MapOfTiles tileCoordForIndex:possibleMove1];
                CGPoint coordinate2 = [MapOfTiles tileCoordForIndex:possibleMove2];

                if([adjSteps containsObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:coordinate1]])
                {
                    //we know that possible move to reach destination has been deemed walkable, get it's move cost from the map
                    moveNode1 = [[MapOfTiles sharedInstance] mapTiles] [possibleMove1];
                }

                if([adjSteps containsObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:coordinate2]])
                {
                    //we know that the second possible move is walkable
                    moveNode2 = [[MapOfTiles sharedInstance] mapTiles] [possibleMove2];
                }

#warning  not sure about this one if the algorithm has to backtrack really far back
                //find out which square has the lowest move cost
                lowestMoveCost = fminf(moveNode1.moveCost, moveNode2.moveCost) * 10;

                moveCost =  (int)sqrt(lowestMoveCost*lowestMoveCost + (stepNode.moveCost*10) * (stepNode.moveCost*10));

            }

            // Compute the cost form the current step to that step


            // Check if the step is already in the open list
            NSUInteger index = [self.spOpenSteps indexOfObject:step];

            if (index == NSNotFound) { // Not on the open list, so add it

                // Set the current step as the parent
                step.parent = currentStep;

                // The G score is equal to the parent G score + the cost to move from the parent to it
                step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost;

                // Compute the H score which is the estimated movement cost to move from that step to the desired tile coordinate
                step.hScore = [self computeHScoreFromCoord:step.position toCoord:toTileCoord];

                // Adding it with the function which is preserving the list ordered by F score
                [self insertInOpenSteps:step];

            }
            else { // Already in the open list

                step = (self.spOpenSteps)[index]; // To retrieve the old one (which has its scores already computed ;-)

                // Check to see if the G score for that step is lower if we use the current step to get there
                if ((currentStep.gScore + moveCost) < step.gScore) {

                    // The G score is equal to the parent G score + the cost to move from the parent to it
                    step.gScore = currentStep.gScore + moveCost;

                    // Because the G Score has changed, the F score may have changed too
                    // So to keep the open list ordered we have to remove the step, and re-insert it with
                    // the insert function which is preserving the list ordered by F score



                    // Now we can removing it from the list without be afraid that it can be released
                    [self.spOpenSteps removeObjectAtIndex:index];

                    // Re-insert it with the function which is preserving the list ordered by F score
                    [self insertInOpenSteps:step];


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems are quite common in, say, chip routing and, yes, gamedev.

Standard approach is to have your graph (in C++ I would say you have Boost "grid graph" or similar structure). If you can afford to have an object each vertex, then the solution is quite easy.

You connect two vertices (neighbors or diagonally adjacent) by an edge, unless there is an obstacle between them. You assign this edge a weight equal to edge length (10 or 14) times terrain cost. Sometimes people prefer not to exclude obstacle edges but assign extremely high weights to them (an advantage is that with such approach you are guaranteed to find at least some path, even when object is stuck at an island).

Then you apply A* algorithm. Your heuristic function (H) can be "pessimistic" (equal to Euclidean distance times the max move cost) or "optimistic" (Euclidean distance times min move cost) or anything in between. Different heuristics will result in slightly different "personalities" of your search but usually do not matter much.